# How to put power function in a formula

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula

I'm fairly new to formulas in excel so bear with me,

I'm trying to write a formula in a specific cell to calculate kinetic energy using the 0,5*m*vˆ2 formula.

So i made a cell for the answers and used a formula for that cell that is as follow `=0,5*$L$3*F3ˆ2` with L3 as the weight (m) and F3 as the velocity (v). But the thing is it gives me a `#NAME?` error for the `F3ˆ2` part. I've changed it to `=0,5*$L$3*POWER(F3,2)` but then it tells me that the `POWER(F3,2)` is invalid.

I'd really want to know why it won't work, I've been googling this for half an hour now but still no answers. I'm using Excel on mac (2011) btw.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're writing 0,5 (with comma) I suppose you don't have English settings on your computer. So you could try to use a semicolon as separator for your function: `=POWER(F3;2)`. You also have to regard the language of your Excel installation. If it is not English you have to replace the `POWER` function by the appropriate in your language (e.g. in German it is `POTENZ`). If you click on the 'fx' symbol on the left on the formula bar you will get support by a wizard.

Comment: Yes it worked! Even though I'm Dutch I have it in English though so the `POWER`function was no problem, only the semicolon. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Those are two different settings. First are the regional settings of your operating system which you can adapt (at least in Windows). E.g. you can switch from `=POWER(2,5;2)` to `=POWER(2.5,2)`. Second is the language pack you installed with you Excel. It is responsible for the language of the formula names. I don't think you can change it without installation of the corresponding Excel version. Obviously you installed the English version as the name would be `MACHT` otherwise. ([As you can see in Wikipedia](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijst_van_Microsoft_Excel-functies))